# How do I find the Microsoft Word normal user template?

Tags: ms-office, library

The path provided elsewhere in this forum—~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/My Templates—doesn't exist on my MacBook Pro, running Yosemite 10.10.5 and Office 2011. I can't even find anything on my machine called "Library," except for one containing fonts in the MS Office application folder.

I want to revise the normal template so that I don't have to use the organizer to activate my preferred style set every time I open a new document. (I mention this in case you know a better way to achieve this aim.)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

~/Library is an usually invisible folder in your user folder.

You may access the folder by entering "~/Library" after choosing Go -> Got to Folder… in the menubar while Finder is the front app.

Alternatively you may open your user folder and change the view options by choosing View -> Show View Options… and enable "Show Library Folder".

Now navigate to ../Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/My Templates and change the normal.dotm as you need.